# Make pairwise comparisons of regression coefficients

Tags: r, statistics, regression

Making pairwise comparisons of correlation cofficients (correlation matrix) is straight forward for a numeric dataframe by using `cor(mydataframe)`. Is there any way to do the same thing for a pairwise comparison for the slope of a simple regression analysis between the same variables? To my disappointment, `slope(mydataframe)` or `beta(mydataframe)` did not do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a built-in function for this, but it's easy to write a for-loop to accomplish this.

```
pairReg = function(data){
  results = rep(NA, ncol(data)**2)
  counter = 0

  for(i in names(data)){
    for (j in names(data)){
      counter = counter + 1
      if (i ==j) next
      results[counter] = lm(data[,i]~data[,j])$coef[2]
    }
  }
  matrix(results, ncol = ncol(data),byrow=T)  
}
```

The function defaults to making the diagonals `NA`.

Example:

```
data = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100,0,1),
              x2 = rnorm(100,0,1),
              x3 = rnorm(100,0,1))
pairReg(data)
```

Could extend this with `apply()` to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **very** straightforward relationship between the covariance matrix of dataset and it's pairwise regression slopes. This is obvious from examining the regression equation and anyone who uses regression should understand this (excuse the fact that latex isn't supported):

**\hat y_i = \bar y + \sigma_{xy} \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x} (x_i - \bar x)**

This implies that the simple linear regression coefficient is

**\hat \Beta = \sigma_{xy} \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}**

IE- the correlation which has been appropriately scaled by the difference in "spread" (standard deviation) between the two variables.

This conversion is therefore straightforward. the answer is similar to @Devon above, but adds in the regression on itself

```
c1 <- cor(data)
c2 <- diag(cov(data)^(1/2))

m <- matrix(NA, nrow= ncol(data), ncol= ncol(data))

for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    m[i,j] <- c1[i,j] * c2[i] / c2[j]
  }
}

# using @devon's data, provided w/o a seed
R> m
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  1.00000000  0.11334817 -0.05551440
[2,]  0.10722557  1.00000000 -0.04449336
[3,] -0.05077282 -0.04301669  1.00000000
```